# How to turn off shadows?

Tags: shadows

I have this 3D model which I imported into blender and the texture is covered by shadows and darkness, how do I turn it off or make it less shadowy?

[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry but how can you hope someone can answer this, or help you? what "covered by shadows" means? does that appear only on rendering results? can you show at least a picture of what you get, better as a 3d view with texturing settings?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/b8960bc81b0a659ccf1a901f34cd7c59.png It's actually quite colorful on the top there, but you can't see it much because it's covered in shadows. Sorry I'm not an expert on these blender stuff.

Comment: ok, better. But please insert that image editing youe question ("edit" link just below the "shadows" tag, then use the editor "add image" button) so it will become part of the question better.

Comment: Ok now to the "shadows": see those two little dashed concentric circles about the middle height of your object, on the right side? Those are part of your scene (only) lamp! So, the light is only coming from there, and it's probably too poorly powered to light your full object. You can either reposition it better (and make its light stronger), add other lamps, or even scale down your big object so it fits better with the rest of the scene, as it is now. It's quite 3d scene setup basic.

Comment: How can I scale the object?

Comment: select the big object (right click on it, by default, it should get an orange outline, as in your picture) , then either press S and  move your mouse, when satisfied left  click; or press S and type (just type don't care where you're "writing") something like 0.1, to get object 10x smaller, then press enter.

Comment: try practicing with lighting basics, following tutorials, etc,  in particular if you need renders (eg: https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/mastering-lighting/#)

Comment: If you are using **Texture** shading mode for viewport display, then you can find **Shadeless** checkbox in the Shading panel in N panel.